# Get Failed Node Endpoint URI in Camel route

Tags: apache-camel

I am developing a sample route

1. **FROM:** SOURCE ENDPOINT URI
2. **TO:**  TRANS  ENDPOINT URI  **// Error or Exception occurred at this TRANS endpoint**
3. **TO:**   TARGET ENDPOINT URI

Now I want to catch the Error Occured endpoint and pass it to my processor.

Could anyone please help me with this?

```html
 <route>
      <from uri="file:C:/MINTS/Source/"/>
       <to uri="file:C:/MINTS/TRANS/"/>  <!-- EXCPECTION OCCURED -->
       <to uri="file:C:/MINTS/TARGET/"/>
       
       <onException>
           <exception>java.lang.Exception</exception>
        <handled>
            <constant>true</constant>
        </handled>
        
        <!-- NEED TO CATCH FAILURE ENDPOINT URI AND PASS TO MY  PROCESSOR BELOW-->
         <process ref="MyExceptionProcessor" />
        
       </onException>
       
     </route>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**You can use exchange properties:**

- **CamelFailureEndpoint**

  - example xml-dsl: `<exchangeProperty>CamelFailureEndpoint</exchangeProperty>`
  - example java: `exchange.getProperty(Exchange.FAILURE_ENDPOINT, String.class);`
- **CamelToEndpoint**

  - example xml-dsl: `<exchangeProperty>CamelToEndpoint</exchangeProperty>`
  - example java: `exchange.getProperty(Exchange.TO_ENDPOINT, String.class)`

The first one should print uri for the consumer endpoint (from) that failed and the second one should show the previously called producer (to) endpoint.

One handy way to debug contexts of an failed exchange is to use:

- `<to uri="log:loggerName?showAll=true" />`

This will log all exchange properties, headers, body and exception which can help to understand what information is available within exchange. **Be careful where you use it as it might also log secrets and passwords if they're within the exchange** so better use it only locally during development.

For more information you'd probably need to access [CamelMessageHistory](https://camel.apache.org/components/3.17.x/eips/message-history.html#_messagehistory_api) exchange property through processor, bean or something.

Comment: Thanks, Its works in my processor by using this    String failedEndpointUri = exchange.getProperty(Exchange.FAILURE_ENDPOINT, String.class);

Comment: Good to hear, added the exchange.getProperty examples to the answer as well for further reference.